# Need to remove every third element and return it once the list has only two elements left

Tags: python-3.x

Need to remove every third element and return it once the list has only two elements left

```
def duck_duck_goose(lst: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    """Given an list of names (strings), play 'duck duck goose' with it,
    knocking out every third name (wrapping around) until only two names are
    left. In other words, when you hit the end of the list, wrap around and keep
    counting from where you were.

    For example, if given this list ['Nathan', 'Sasha', 'Sara', 'Jennie'], you'd
    first knock out Sara. Then first 'duck' on Jennie, wrap around to 'duck' on
    Nathan and 'goose' on Sasha - knocking him out and leaving only Nathan and
    Jennie.

    You may assume the list has 3+ names to start

    Args:
        lst - a list of names (strings)

    Returns:
        the resulting list after playing duck duck goose
    """

    raise NotImplementedError("duck_duck_goose")

names = ["sasha", "nathan", "jennie", "shane", "will", "sara"]
assert duck_duck_goose(names) == ["sasha", "will"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short snippet on how you can do it,

```
names = ["sasha", "nathan", "jennie", "shane", "will", "sara"]

def removeThirdName(names): 

    pos = 3 - 1
    index = 0
    len_list = (len(names)) 

    while len_list > 2:  

        index = (pos + index) % len_list 

        print(names.pop(index))
        len_list -= 1

removeThirdName(names)
print(names)
```

Outputs:

```
['sasha', 'will']
```